# Sftp OutboundAdapter with multiple folders

Tags: java, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I need to transfer the file from Local to multiple sftp server folders. 
This is my code so far,  I'm transferring one to one basis with single channel:

```
private IntegrationFlow localToRemotePush(final String localDirectory,String remoteDirectory, String adapterName) {    
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Files.inboundAdapter(Paths.get(localDirectory).toFile())
                                .regexFilter(FILE_PATTERN_REGEX)
                                .preventDuplicates(false),
                        e -> {
                            e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(getPollerIntervalMs())
                                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(getMaxFetchSize())
                                    .errorChannel("errorChannel")
                                    .transactional(transactionManager)
                                    .transactionSynchronizationFactory(mmPushSftpSyncFactory()) // moves processed files
                            ).id(adapterName);
                        })
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(mmPushSftpSessionFactory())
                        .remoteDirectory(getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory1)
                        //.remoteDirectory(getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory2) --- this way is correct ?
                        .temporaryFileSuffix(".tmp"))
            .get();
}
```

Is it possible to transfer local files from one local folder to multiple sftp folders using single channel?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible with a single `Sftp.outboundAdapter()`. It is designed only for a single remote directory which, however, can be determined from the request message by the function or expression. But that's different story.

Your task can be achieved with several `Sftp.outboundAdapter()` for each remote directory and `publishSubscribe` configuration. Something like this:

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(mmPushSftpSessionFactory())
                                          .remoteDirectory(getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory1)
                                          .temporaryFileSuffix(".tmp")))
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(mmPushSftpSessionFactory())
                                          .remoteDirectory(getRemoteRootDir() + remoteDirectory2)
                                          .temporaryFileSuffix(".tmp")))
                )
```

Comment: Thanks Artem , is it possible to change file file name  from Local to Remote ?
 tried SFTP.Outbound this 
 .fileNameExpression("payload.getName().replaces('HIGH_VAL',VAL')")
I tried like this but I am getting this error 
EL1004E: Method call: Method replaces(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be found on java.lang.String type

Comment: Because the method name is `replace()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: You can use `fileNameGenerator()` instead for better content assistant for its lambda